# Facebook php login status

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to do something similar to the login/registration flow described on this page but via php only.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

What I want to do is display a register link if a user is logged in to facebook but not registered with my site, and a login link if they're not logged in to facebook, however I want to do this all on my side in php, and not using the fb:login-button widget. Is this possible?

I have the login url working, i just want to change the name of the button based on the users status.

Comment: You want the functionality of Facebook's API without using Facebook's API?

Comment: No I want to find out if the user is logged in to facebook so i can show a "register" button instead of a "login" one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it without loading the javascript lib. If you load nothing from Facebook on the client, then there is no way to do cross domain communication (security). Which means there is no way to tell who the user is, much less if they are logged into Facebook. By loading the javascript API on the client, the javascript code can check for a Facebook cookie and determine who they are and whether they are logged into Facebook or not.

Check through javascript and do a page reload if need be. Better yet, just use css to show/hide what you want.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Yeah it's looking increasingly like this is what i have to do. I also found this which was an interesting read on the subject. https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Comment: @ricick: Don't use that method, you're likely to get flagged as malicious.

Comment: Good point. I'll just label the button generically to match both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Here's a tutorial:
[Tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/), 
[Example tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/demo/newfbconnect1/php/index.php)

Comment: This is not what i mean. I already have the login flow for my site working. I want to determine if a user is logged in to facebook at all, similar to the way the login/registration button does different things in these circumstances.